# How to move continuous data in to the files for every 15 minutes using java

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

There will be data coming continuously from x device i need to move them in to files for every 15minutes please share some ideas how we can do this one in java.

Comment: You need scheduled task and file copy. Which of these two is giving you problems ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set threads or use a scheduler like Quartz
http://quartz-scheduler.org/

You only need to schedule a task every 15 minutes with quartz, then move your files into the task

First, import quartz dependency with maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then make a Job class

```
public class MoveFilesJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        // TODO move your files here

    }

}
```

Finally, make a trigger and run it

```
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MoveFilesJob.class)
            .withIdentity("moveFileJob", "group1").build();


    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("moveFileTrigger", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInMinutes(15).repeatForever())
            .build();

    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Quartz strikes me as overkill but would certainly work. But using a thread and sleep instead of executors in 2015 is inexcusable.

Comment: It was just to show a simple way. No need to vote down for this...

Comment: Actually that's exactly how this works: downvote bad answers, upvote good ones. If you removed the thread part and just showed hire the quartz solution actually worked (not just a link!) This would certainly qualify as a good alternative to the other answer and deserve an upvote.

Comment: Ok I removed the thread sleep part and enhance the quartz solution

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework in java SE since java 1.5.

More specifically for your use case the class [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) contains method [newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29). Which will return new [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instance. Use that service to schedule some [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) implementing work you need to do. Following code snippet illustrates the idea.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
   Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();


 final Runnable myWorkingRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() { System.out.println("Working"); }
 };

 final ScheduledFuture<?> workHandler =
   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myWorkingRunnable , 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

You may use `workHandler` or `scheduler` to further manipulation with the service or scheduled `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks but how to process the data in to files which was coming from device. Since it is continuous process. Scheduler method will called only after 15 minutes but what about the data which was coming continuously coming from x device.

Comment: Please specify how the data are coming? Through stream? Or are they placed to some URL/Directory? And what exactly you mean by x device?